# Reloading cells while moving with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

There are many many questions on this, but I can't find the answer to my problem. I am reordering my cells with core-data, but I am getting duplicate cells while editing and scrolling. The reorder works just fine, and if I reload the view after editing is complete, they are all in the correct order. How can I reload the cells that are moved to stop getting duplicates?

Here is my moveRow method. Like I said it works just fine, except for duplicate cells.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    if ([fromIndexPath isEqual:toIndexPath]) {
        return;
    }
    self.userDrivenDataModelChange = YES;
    NSMutableArray *sortedObjects = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];
    // Get a handle to the call we're moving
    MyObject *myObjectMovingFrom = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
    MyObject *myObjectMovingTo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:toIndexPath];

    int indexFrom = (int)[sortedObjects indexOfObject:myObjectMovingFrom];
    int indexTo = (int)[sortedObjects indexOfObject:myObjectMovingTo];
    // Remove the call from it's current position
    [sortedObjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexFrom];
    // Insert it at it's new position
    [sortedObjects insertObject:myObjectMovingFrom atIndex:indexTo];
    int i = 1;
    for (MyObject *myObject in sortedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"MyObject Moving: %@", myObject.myObjectName);
        [myObject setStudioListPositionValue:i];
        NSLog(@"MEW STUDIO LIST POSITION: %d", i);
        i++;
    }
    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
    self.userDrivenDataModelChange = NO;
}
```

All of my other NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods are wrapped in the following as recommended.

```
if (self.userDrivenDataModelChange)
        return;
{
   ...
}
```

If I put a `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in my move method, It crashes saying I am trying to reload a cell that is no longer there.

How can I refresh the TableView so I don't get the duplicate cells?

Answer (score 0):

After removing an object with:

```
[sortedObjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexFrom];
```

indexTo may need adjustment before inserting with:

```
[sortedObjects insertObject:myObjectMovingFrom atIndex:indexTo];
```

I would suggest adding a break point here to check sortedObjects and make sure the result is expected.